# Mysterious vertical space when using \newcommand with expex

Tags: spacing, macros, expex

Ok, so here's some code that shows off the problem i'm having:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\newcommand{\gloss}[3]{\ex[numoffset=2em,aboveglftskip=0pt]
\begingl
\gla #1//
\glb #2//
\glft #3//
\endgl
\xe}

\begin{document}
\gloss123

blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

\ex[numoffset=2em,aboveglftskip=0pt]
\begingl
\gla 1//
\glb 2//
\glft 3//
\endgl
\xe

blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

\end{document}
```

This is the output it makes:[image]

As you can see, there's extra vertical space between the first gloss and the blahs. How can I get rid of this while still using \newcommand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stems from the fact that `\gloss{.}{.}{.}` leaves a spurious space in the input stream. You can avoid this by placing a `%` at the end, or by adding `\ignorespaces` at the end of your `\newcommand` definition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\newcommand{\gloss}[3]{\ex[numoffset=2em,aboveglftskip=0pt]
\begingl
\gla #1//
\glb #2//
\glft #3//
\endgl
\xe
\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\gloss{1}{2}{3}%

blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

\ex[numoffset=2em,aboveglftskip=0pt]
\begingl
\gla 1//
\glb 2//
\glft 3//
\endgl
\xe

blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening but we can work around the issue by adding an negative vertical space `\vspace{-\baselineskip}}` at the end of the command.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\newcommand{\gloss}[3]{\ex[numoffset=2em,aboveglftskip=0pt]
\begingl
\gla #1//
\glb #2//
\glft #3//
\endgl
\xe
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
}
\begin{document}
\gloss123

blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

\ex[numoffset=2em,aboveglftskip=0pt]
\begingl
\gla 1//
\glb 2//
\glft 3//
\endgl
\xe

blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like Werner's solution better but this is good to know as well.

Comment: @jakeh I agree with you that Werner's solution is by far better